# Got runtime exception after adding crosswalk-lite with ionic-cli

Tags: ionic-framework

Has anyone tried the crosswalk-lite? I added it to my project. The build process was fine. But when I ran my app, it broke down. I got below exception:

```
Process: com.ionicframework.xwalklite698410, PID: 23439
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ionicframework.xwalklite698410/com.ionicframework.xwalklite698410.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview.
```

Is there anyone get the same problem?

Comment: same problem, it works in some of the devices, but not some;

Answer (score 2):

### Hey there,

We had the same `issue`. After investigating the `logs` using `logcat` We found out that the cause is `permissions` issue.

just add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml`

If it still does not work add an extra `permission`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Good luck,

#### P.S

(if you find some way to added those in `config.xml` i'll be happy to hear about that :)

Comment: You mean what to add?

Comment: yes, you need those permissions on order to work with crosswalk

Comment: I have same issue too. My `AndroidManifest.xml` had those two lines, but still not work. You can see my post :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452079/ionic-starter-cant-run-on-crosswalk-lite-unable-to-start-activity-componentinf

Comment: already have `android.permission.INTERNET`,`android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`,`android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` in manifest file, not work.

Comment: maybe you can add the full log file?

Comment: am.. seems like abug. maybe report to project ? https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-lite-10.html