# Ionic starter can't run on crosswalk-lite: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I am starting ionic app with crosswalk-lite, but it can't run on both real device & genymotion.

```
ionic start myApp tabs
npm install
bower install
ionic serve # <-- I test on browser & it's work
ionic browser add crosswalk-lite
ionic build android # <-- success to compile
ionic run android # <-- run on genymotion, and it's crash
```

When I do `adb logcat`, it show error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ionicframework.myapp}`

[image: error adb logcat]

I build with:

- node v0.10.36
- ionic 1.4.5
- cordova 4.3.0

Plugin:

- com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4
- cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.0.1-dev
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0
- org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13
- org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0
- org.apache.cordova.splashcsreen 1.0.0

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.ionicframework.vellfire661565" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.ionicframework.vellfire661565" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.ionicframework.vellfire661565.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ionicframework.vellfire661565.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

And this is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.vellfire661565" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>SS Shop</name>
    <description>
        SS Shop.
    </description>
    <author email="" href="">
    Silviana Suteja
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File Transfer">
        <param name="id" value="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Toast">
        <param name="id" value="nl.x-services.plugins.toast" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="PushPlugin">
        <param name="id" value="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" />
        <param name="url" value="https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="AppVersion">
        <param name="id" value="uk.co.whiteoctober.cordova.appversion" />
        <param name="url" value="https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Network Information">
        <param name="id" value="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    </feature>
    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resourc  es/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="Media Refresher">
        <param name="id" value="com.metacube.metacampus.mediarefresher" />
        <param name="url" value="https://github.com/saurabhgupta050890/Media-Refresher-Cordova.git" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

`adb logcat` return:

```
W/InputMethodManagerService(  313): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain
of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@53864848 attribute=n
ull
W/genymotion_audio(  125): out_write() limiting sleep time 81156 to 39909
W/genymotion_audio(  125): out_write() limiting sleep time 62426 to 39909
I/ActivityManager(  313): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.int
ent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.ionicframework.vellfire661565/.Mai
nActivity u=0} from pid 484
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 764896 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 715744 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 666592 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 617440 bytes, got 16384
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 601056 bytes, got 87280
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 513776 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 464624 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 415472 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 366320 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 317168 bytes, got 294912
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 22256 bytes, got 16384
D/dalvikvm(  313): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 746K, 11% free 15401K/17159K, paused 10ms,
 total 10ms
D/dalvikvm( 1054): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  313): Start proc com.ionicframework.vellfire661565 for activ
ity com.ionicframework.vellfire661565/.MainActivity: pid=1054 uid=10048 gids={30
03, 1015, 1028}
I/qtaguid (  313): Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10048) res=-1 errno=1
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(  313): setKernelCountSet(10048, 1) failed with
errno -1
D/OpenGLRenderer(  484): TextureCache::flush: target size: 651434
D/OpenGLRenderer(  484): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 592
, 59536, 1026188
D/OpenGLRenderer(  484): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 593
, 204880, 821308
D/OpenGLRenderer(  484): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 594
, 204880, 616428
I/CordovaLog( 1054): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
D/AndroidRuntime( 1054): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1054): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa
624f288)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{com.ionicframework.vellfire661565/com.ionicframework.vellfire661565.
MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview.
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivi
ty(ActivityThread.java:2084)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(Activit
yThread.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac
tivityThread.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
11)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1054): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create
 webview.
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createE
ngine(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebVie
wEngine(CordovaActivity.java:192)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebVie
w(CordovaActivity.java:188)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(Cordo
vaActivity.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(Co
rdovaActivity.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at com.ionicframework.vellfire661565.MainActivit
y.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.j
ava:5008)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCre
ate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative
(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Con
structor.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createE
ngine(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        ... 19 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWal
kPreferences.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView.setGlob
alPrefs(XWalkCordovaView.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView.<init>(
XWalkCordovaView.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkWebViewEngine.<init
>(XWalkWebViewEngine.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1054):        ... 22 more
W/ActivityManager(  313):   Force finishing activity com.ionicframework.vellfire
661565/.MainActivity
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 764896 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 715744 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 666592 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 617440 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 568288 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 519136 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 469984 bytes, got 245760
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 224224 bytes, got 16384
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 207840 bytes, got 13804
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 194036 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 144884 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 95732 bytes, got 49152
E/SocketStream(  122): readFully was waiting for 46580 bytes, got 32768
D/dalvikvm(  313): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 540K, 11% free 15377K/17159K, paused 12ms,
 total 12ms
E/Genymotion(  313): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_pat
h/present'
W/ActivityManager(  313): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{5385639c com
.ionicframework.vellfire661565/.MainActivity}
W/EGL_genymotion(  484): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
I/qtaguid (  313): Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10048) res=-1 errno=1
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(  313): setKernelCountSet(10048, 0) failed with
errno -1
E/Genymotion(  313): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_pat
h/present'
E/Genymotion(  313): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_pat
h/present'
W/ActivityManager(  313): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{5385639c c
om.ionicframework.vellfire661565/.MainActivity}
```

Comment: Can you add the full log of the exception? The screen shot does not show all the trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your steps and it works good.

I have :
- cordova 5.3.1
- ionic version 1.1.0
- ionic CLI version 1.6.4

You should try to update and see if it works.